# How do I list Access Form control names from another database?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I went to a Access Meetup Group recently and saw a rather cool idea demonstrated; create a code library database that holds code to return names and properties of tables, forms etc from a database then reference from the database being developed. By doing so I have a modal form that can tell me what tables I have, what fields are in them etc with all the code housed in the code library which I can then un-reference when I'm done. The problem I'm facing is how to loop through the forms collection to list the forms and their controls that exist in the calling database as I can't use CurrentDb like I can for tables. I've been searching Google, and even ventured on to the second results page, and have found Containers which might be what I am loking for but I can't make it work. I'm 99% certain that the guy giving the demo showed forms listed in his modal form. (Foolishly I didn't get his name or else I'd contact him).

I've tried using CurrentProject.Application.Forms but Access says it can't find the form. Does it need to be open for this to work?

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Any ideas I can try?

PS: I cross posted this from UtterAccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Forms" collection is for only currently open forms within Access.  You will need to use the 'AllForms' collection, which returns an 'AccessObject' to then determine if the form is loaded or not.  Once you've determined if the form is opened or not, you can then open it and grab the object reference and then loop through the controls.  This should get you started.

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    ListAllFormsAndControls Access.Application
End Sub

Public Sub ListAllFormControls(acApp As Access.Application)

    Dim frmAcObj As Access.AccessObject
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Dim ctl As Access.Control
    Dim closeForm As Boolean


    For Each frmAcObj In acApp.CurrentProject.AllForms

        closeForm = False

        If frmAcObj.IsLoaded = False Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm frmAcObj.Name, windowmode:=acHidden
            closeForm = True
        End If

        Set frm = Access.Forms(frmAcObj.Name)

            For Each ctl In frm.Controls

                Debug.Print frm.Name & " | " & ctl.Name & "(" & TypeName(ctl) & ")"

            Next ctl

        If closeForm Then
            DoCmd.Close acForm, frmAcObj.Name
        End If

    Next frmAcObj
End Sub
```

Sample Results:

```
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct1(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct2(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct3(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct4(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct5(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct6(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct7(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct8(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct9(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct10(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct11(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct12(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct13(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct14(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct15(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct16(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct17(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct18(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct19(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Pct20(TextBox)
F_ProgressBar | txt_Desc(TextBox)
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I was kind of heading in that direction with the AllForms but I wouldn't have come up with the "isLoaded" bit on my own.

Comment: With a few tweaks I was able to adapt this code to what I needed. Thanks again @Fink